# add line to files tooltip using C#

Tags: c#, tooltip

Im trying to find a way to add linesto files\folder tooltip using C#.

for example when I would point on some file in window I could see it's name and also some customize information. for example in the following file I would like to add the current version of Itunes program.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The file you would want to modify is called Desktop.ini

To modify/create .ini files with C#, refer to this article from codeproject.com

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C

The Class

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Ini
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a New INI file to store or load data
    /// </summary>
    public class IniFile
    {
        public string path;

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
            string key,string val,string filePath);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
                 string key,string def, StringBuilder retVal,
            int size,string filePath);

        /// <summary>
        /// INIFile Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="INIPath"></PARAM>
        public IniFile(string INIPath)
        {
            path = INIPath;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Write Data to the INI File
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="Section"></PARAM>
        /// Section name
        /// <PARAM name="Key"></PARAM>
        /// Key Name
        /// <PARAM name="Value"></PARAM>
        /// Value Name
        public void IniWriteValue(string Section,string Key,string Value)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString(Section,Key,Value,this.path);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read Data Value From the Ini File
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="Section"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="Key"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="Path"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string IniReadValue(string Section,string Key)
        {
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
            int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section,Key,"",temp, 
                                            255, this.path);
            return temp.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, how can I see the data in the ini files? and what i should change if the requested file is not located on the desktop

Comment: @RomanTmur  Desktop.ini files are all over the place. They control the appearance and behavior of individual files and folders. You can view them by enabling the show hidden files in your folder options of windows since they are hidden by default.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini